# Password reminder notification for internal users

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder

I have requirement to generate password reminder notifications to Internal users.

similar article for more info- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60315/email-notification-on-password-expiration

source blog- http://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/email-notification-on-password-expiration/

I tried with process builder and workflow rule, noticed that the workflow/process builder works on field updates (last modified date/username/other fields).

The source blog working fine but it requires manual activity to update the custom field on user object and workflow rule gets executed. By using this approach will not perform customizations in subscriber orgs.

But these are not executed for "Last Password Change or Reset" this field.

Can you please share your ideas/suggestions to implement this requirement.

The idea link for more information on this

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqBY

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a strange use case.

Normally, if the password expires then the *next time* the user attempts to log in they will be required to change it.

Your use case is that they get a notification even before they log in. The normal user response would be "I don't care, I'll change it next time I log in thanks".